# Need Help fixing my page loading spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden div that gets displayed when a button is clicked that shows a spinner, but if you hit the back button after leaving the page the spinner is still visible. I think the javascript needs the `$(document).ready(function() {` but I'm not sure how to implement it. I don't want the spinner visible if the user presses the back button.

This is what I have so far. The Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = "block";
}

</script>
```

The Div and link used to show the div

```
<div id="spinner"  style="display:none;" class="spinner" ><img src="images/loader2.gif" alt="Loading"/></div>

<a class="index_buttons" href="search_members.php" onclick="showDiv()">Search Members </a>
```

Comment: The browser probably "remembers" the JavaScript code and re-executing it. In such case your only real option is to disable getting back to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're tagged this as jQuery..

```
/* Calls this function on ready */
$(function() {
  /* Hide the spinner whenever the page loads */
  $("#spinner").hide();
      ;
  $(".index_buttons").click(function() { $("#spinner").show(); });
});
```

Now, everytime a button with the class `index_buttons` is clicked, the button will be visible. If you want to toggle the spinner, you might want to look at `toggle()`.

Comment: is there a way to use ID instead of using the class? Just Wondering.

Answer (score 2):

To hide the spinner on page load do:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#spinner").hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use document ready as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    hideSpinner(); // Initiates the hide function when document is ready.
});

function hideSpinner() {
   $('#spinner').hide();
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't hide the div when I leave the page and come back. I thought this is what I was looking for.